# Is there a way I can compare two object using ES7 Set or Map method?

Tags: javascript

I have two set of javascript objects.

```
const object1 = {
  checkedB: false,
  inqueryProcess: "inqury",
  inquryChannel: 0,
  inquryDate: undefined,
  inquryManager: "Option 1",
  inquryMemo: "",
  inquryRoute: 0,
  inquryTitle: 0,
  radio1: "common",
  radio2: "none"
}

const object2 = {
  checkedB: false,
  inquryMemo: "",
  inquryChannel: 0,
  inquryDate: undefined,
  inquryTitle: 0,
  radio2: "none"
  inquryManager: "Option 1",
  inqueryProcess: "inqury",
  inquryRoute: 0,
  radio1: "common",
}
```

I have two set of objects which exactly the same and I want to compare both whether they have equal value.

Of course I can take advantage of JSON.stringfy but I want to avoid it due to order issue.

Therefore I want to use es7 new Map or Set method to make comparing faster and efficient.

I added these values into new Set like this below.

```
    const newSet1 = new Set();
    const newSet2 = new Set();

    Object.values(object1).forEach(val => newSet1.add(val));
    Object.values(object2).forEach(val => newSet2.add(val))

    console.log(newSet1);
    console.log(newSet2)
```

Now newSet1 and newSet2 contain values of object1 and object2.

How can I compare these two whether they have same set of value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and check the key/value pairs from the other object and delete existing keys. At the end check if the length of the map is zero.

```js
const
    isEqual = (a, b) => {
        const map = new Map(Object.entries(a));
        return Object
                .entries(b)
                .every(([k, v]) => map.get(k) === v && map.delete(k)) &&
            !map.size;
    },
    object1 = { checkedB: false, inqueryProcess: "inqury", inquryChannel: 0, inquryDate: undefined, inquryManager: "Option 1",inquryMemo: "", inquryRoute: 0, inquryTitle: 0, radio1: "common", radio2: "none" }, 
    object2 = { checkedB: false, inqueryProcess: "inqury", inquryChannel: 0, inquryDate: undefined, inquryManager: "Option 1", inquryMemo: "", inquryRoute: 0, inquryTitle: 0, radio1: "common", radio2: "none" };

console.log(isEqual(object1, object2));
```